# Linkmap graph using 3DJS

Tags: d3.js

I have a website linking map in a csv file. it is represented by 2 column, one for Origin URL and one for Target URL
I would like to draw a chart that represent the relationship between all pages. I'm looking for a logic to implement that make me draw the chart using 3DJS

I used the collapsed force layout of 3DJS https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288

As you can see, the JS parse a JSON file that represent the relationship between nodes.

here is what my mapping looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W2bx.jpg

Currently, I have my data stored in a database. I can parse it and create a JSON/CSV file. I'm looking for an appropriate format for that JSON file

any help ?

Comment: I think that the problem that you are trying to solve is how to prepare your data for rendering. Please check this codepen: https://codepen.io/cstefanache/pen/ZZzQWX and let me know if this is the desired output

Comment: @Cornel Stefanache thank you so much for your answer, i appreciate it ! yes it's kind of what i'm trying to do :), I tried to test your code, but it can't find d3.forceSimulation function, where do you call for d3 ressources ? to give you an example of what i want to achieve: https://imgur.com/TT4jOWB

Comment: What version of D3 are you using? if you are using version 3 then the force would be like: ```d3.layout.force()```. Here is a sample block for v3: https://bl.ocks.org/wnghdcjfe/b7cb2e1f479b9998a5fe3d7c5eb9fbdd but I suggest to migrate to v4 or 5

Comment: it's ok, your script is working well. have you an idea to make it work by directory ? (i mean regroupe the points by directory in the URL

Comment: Please create a gist with data and I can update the code

Comment: hi Cornel, here is the gist https://gist.github.com/karibot/dbcec6e57ed6c5df513316e028197773
I attached a links.js containing "serverData" coming from my real website mapping. here is an image of the expected results https://imgur.com/Jsb0zKf (is it ok for you)?

Comment: I updated the original codepen but I am afraid that the most of the nodes are linked to the rest of the nodes (44 nodes - 795 edges with duplicates removed). The desired output is not looking as you would expect

Comment: @CornelStefanache
I get the same chart, i wonder what if we create other nodes but spliting URLs into categories.ex: /category/food/url.html, will create 2 others nodes /category/ and /food/